# QML component collapses while moving across screens

Tags: qt, qml

When I move my QML app back and forth several times across the screens of different DPIs, the Window (ID: offCanvasComp) just loses its dimensions and gets larger or smaller inconsistently.
Clicking on it brings its dimensions back.

The idea is to make a off canvas drawer. I am using frameless window.
OS: Windows 10

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    maximumWidth: 800
    minimumHeight: 600
    minimumWidth: 800
    maximumHeight: 600
    color: "seagreen"

    // Qt.Window enables the ico to be on taskbar as Qt.FrameLessWindowHint hides it too.
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint /*| Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint*/ | Qt.Window

    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent
        DragHandler {
            acceptedDevices: PointerDevice.Generic
            grabPermissions:  PointerHandler.CanTakeOverFromItems | PointerHandler.CanTakeOverFromHandlersOfDifferentType | PointerHandler.ApprovesTakeOverByAnything
            onActiveChanged:
                if (active)
                {
                    offCanvasComp.visible=false
                    root.startSystemMove()
                }
                else{
                    offCanvasComp.visible=true
                }

        }
    }

    Window
    {
        id: offCanvasComp
        flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window
        color: "teal"
        maximumWidth:20
        minimumHeight: 60
        minimumWidth: 20
        maximumHeight: 60
        x: root.x + root.width
        y: root.y
        visible: true

        Rectangle
        {
            id: drawerOpener
            height: offCanvasComp.height
            width: offCanvasComp.width
            border.color: "silver"
            border.width: 1
            color: "white"

            Text {
                id: opener
                //antialiasing: true
                text: String.fromCharCode(0x25BA)
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                font.pointSize: 15
            }

            MouseArea
            {
                id: hoverIt
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onEntered: drawerOpener.color="silver"
                onExited: drawerOpener.color="white"
                onPressed:
                {
                    offCanvasComp.width=50
                    offCanvasComp.height=60
                    drawer.open()
                    drawerOpener.color="darkgray"
                }
                onReleased: drawerOpener.color="white"

            }
        }

        Drawer
        {
            id: drawer
            width: 50
            height: 60
            interactive: false
            Row
            {
                id: row
                Column
                {
                    id: col
                    width: 30
                    height: 60
                    Button
                    {
                        id: closeIt
                        text: "\u2715"
                        width: 30
                        height: 30
                        Rectangle
                        {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            color: "white"
                            border.width: 1
                            border.color: "silver"
                            MouseArea
                            {
                                anchors.fill: parent
                                hoverEnabled: true
                                onEntered: parent.color="red"
                                onExited: parent.color="white"
                                onPressed:
                                {
                                    parent.border.color="darkred"
                                    parent.color="darkred"
                                }
                                onReleased:
                                {
                                    parent.border.color= "silver"
                                    parent.color="white"
                                }
                                onClicked: Shutter.exit()
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    Button
                    {
                        id: minIt
                        text: "\u2212"
                        height: 30
                        width: 30
                        Rectangle
                        {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            color: "white"
                            border.width: 1
                            border.color: "silver"
                            MouseArea
                            {
                                anchors.fill: parent
                                hoverEnabled: true
                                onEntered: parent.color="silver"
                                onExited: parent.color="white"
                                onPressed: parent.color="darkgray"
                                onReleased: parent.color="white"
                                onClicked: showMinimized()
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                Button
                {
                    id: reverse
                    text: String.fromCharCode(0x25C4)
                    width: 20
                    height: 60
                    Rectangle
                    {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        color: "white"
                        border.width: 1
                        border.color: "silver"
                        MouseArea
                        {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            hoverEnabled: true
                            onEntered: parent.color="silver"
                            onExited: parent.color="white"
                            onPressed: parent.color="darkgray"
                            onReleased: parent.color="white"
                            onClicked:
                            {
                                offCanvasComp.width=20
                                offCanvasComp.height=60
                                drawer.close()
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure those screens only have different resolutions? Maybe they have different DPI settings. What OS?